# Reading data from csv into pyspark (Aesthetic Look)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

When reading data from csv into pyspark dataframe , its look is very bad (not even able to read). Is there any way to enhance the look . I tried using header but no change [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuSaT.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBw5a.png)

Comment: I dont want to convert it not pandas dataframe . I am only looking for pyspark answers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `display(df)` instead of `df.show()`?

Ashutosh Sharma has asked why he gets an output of just one column, and the answer is that the `df` may be a series with multiple indices.

To display the indices as well as the data, we can use `display(df.reset_index())`

Comment: Yes I tried but it is returning only column name and its datatype

Comment: @AshutoshSharma I have edited the answer to adapt the solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to deal with rows that overflow (when you have several columns) is to use `df.show(vertical=True, truncate=False)`

Alternatively you can convert plthe PySpark dataframe into a pandas dataframe that has better rendering in most IDEs (Jupyter, Pycharm)

Comment: yes I tried .. Although it is looking better from previous answer but this is defeating the whole purpose of using dataframes as i have large volume of data

Comment: AFAIK there is no native way to beautify the dataframe in pyspark other than vertical view. Depending on your requirements you could either
1. Convert the dataframe to a pandas dataframe and use an IDE like PyCharm to visualize it (there is a horizontal scroll and some basic conditional formatting as well).
2. Write the dataframe to a csv / xlsx / ods and visualise it using your spreadsheet application
3. Use a dedicated visualization framework like plotly / dash / matplotlib to render the dataframe in a browser